# Excle VBA Code for searching existing data in sheet2

Tags: excel, vba

I need code for below item

if 
value of the data entered in cell B9 in sheet1 exist in sheet2 Column A2:A5000,
identify and replace the existing record

else 
create new row and update details

Answer (score 0):

I have started this for you, you just have to finish the replace code. You can use my hint's in msgboxes for it.

```
Option Explicit
Sub find_and_replace()
Dim whSrc           As Worksheet: Set whSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim whDest          As Worksheet: Set whDest = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Dim strToFind       As String: strToFind = whSrc.Range("B9").Value
Dim RngToLookIn     As Range: Set RngToLookIn = whDest.Range("A2:A5000")
Dim rngFoundRange As Range


Set rngFoundRange = RngToLookIn.Find(What:=strToFind, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

If Not rngFoundRange Is Nothing Then
    'Your replace code
    MsgBox ("Found in Row: " & rngFoundRange.Row)
Else
    'not found, your new row code goes here
    MsgBox ("Last row: " & RngToLookIn.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row)
End If

End Sub
```

ps. Next time do not start your post with "i need". Show, what you already coded, what's your problem etc.